# Animate the width of a Rectangle over time

Tags: animation, swiftui, watchos

In SwiftUI on WatchOS, how can I animate the width of a Rectangle (or any View for that matter) so that it starts at a certain value and over a specified time animates to a different value?

Specifically, I want to animate a Rectangle to indicate the time left to the next full minute or the next 30 seconds after a minute.

All the examples I've seen are based on `Timer.scheduledTimer` firing at relatively high speed and setting a `@State` variable, but my understanding is that especially on WatchOS this should be avoided. Is there a better way?

This is the timer/state based code I have but I feel like there should be a more efficient way:

```swift
import SwiftUI

func percentage() -> CGFloat {
    1 - CGFloat(fmod(Date().timeIntervalSince1970, 30) / 30)
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State var ratio: CGFloat = percentage()

    let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1 / 60, on:.main, in:.common).autoconnect()

    var body: some View {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                    .frame(width:geometry.size.width, height:5)
                HStack {
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(Color.red)
                        .frame(width:geometry.size.width * self.ratio, height:5)
                    Spacer()
                }
            }
        }.onReceive(self.timer) { _ in
            self.ratio = percentage()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a "more efficient way" to use animation:

```swift
struct AnimationRectangle: View {

    struct AnimationRectangle: View {

    @State private var percentage: CGFloat = 0.0
    // count, how much time left to nearest 30 seconds
    @State private var animationDuration = 30 - Double(fmod(Date().timeIntervalSince1970, 30)) 
    private var repeatedAnimationFor30Seconds: Animation {
        return Animation.easeInOut(duration: 30)
            .repeatForever(autoreverses: false)
    }

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            // just showing duration of current animation
            Text("\(self.animationDuration)")

            ZStack {
                Rectangle()
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)

                GeometryReader { geometry in
                    HStack {
                        Rectangle()
                            .foregroundColor(.green)
                            .frame(width: geometry.size.width * self.percentage)

                        Spacer()
                    }
                }


            }
            .frame(height: 5)
            .onAppear() {

                // first animation without repeating
                withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut(duration: self.animationDuration)) {
                    self.percentage = 1.0
                }

                // other repeated animations
                DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + self.animationDuration) {
                    self.percentage = 0.0
                    self.animationDuration = 30.0
                    withAnimation(self.repeatedAnimationFor30Seconds) {
                        self.percentage = 1.0
                    }
                }

            }
        }

    }
}
struct AnimationRectangle_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AnimationRectangle()
    }
}
```

Comment: how would I handle the fact that the first animation does not take the full 30 seconds but rather however long it takes to the next full minute or 30 seconds after the minute? For example, if it's 12:12:12 the animation should take 18 seconds.